# Out-of-line definition does not match any declaration

Tags: c++

I am stuck with an error I don't understand. I have declared `Student` and coded the following string.

Below is my code, the error happens at:

`Student::Student(string studentID, string firstName, string lastName etc...`

```
Student::Student(string studentID, string firstName, string lastName, string emailAddress, int age, DegreeProgram degreeProgram, int daysInCourse[])
{
    studentID = studentID;
    firstName = firstName;
    lastName = lastName;
    emailAddress = emailAddress;
    age = 46;
    degreeProgram = degreeProgram;
    for (int index = 0; index < daysToCompleteArraySize; index++) {
        daysInCourse[index] = daysInCourse[index];
    }
```

Below is the `.hpp` file:

```
#include "degree.hpp"
#include <string>
#pragma once
using std::string;

class Student {

public:
    
    // Constructor
    Student(string studentID, string firstName, string lastName, string emailAddress, int age, DegreeProgram degree, std::vector<int> daysInCourse[]);
    Student();

public:const static int daysToCompleteArraySize = 3;

private:
    string studentID;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string emailAddress;
    int age;
    DegreeProgram degreeProgram;
    int daysInCourse[daysToCompleteArraySize];
```

Comment: *"...does not match any declaration"* usually requires the pasting of one `class` declaration or more.

Comment: How does the compiler determine the difference between the *member* `studentID` and the *parameter* `studentID`? In your code it looks like you are copying the same variable to itself.  Hint:  Use different names between parameters and members.  Some coding styles prefix member names with "m_" other styles append a "_" to the member names.  Some people use a thesaurus to come up with different names. ;-)

Comment: Also, pass `std::string` by reference or `const` reference if the string is modified.  You don't want the compiler making copies of all those parameters when it calls the constructor.

Comment: Since you have a constructor, consider using *initialization lists*.  Search the internet for "C++ rule 0/3/5".

Comment: Thank you for suck a quick response. So for the member I could user m_studentID for member and for the parameter just use studentID?

Comment: in my .hpp file I've stated the below for passing std::string.      
#include "degree.hpp"
#include <string>
#pragma once
using std::string;

class Student {

Comment: Please make a [mre]

Comment: Hello @cigien here is a snippet of the code.   include "student.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int age = 46;

Student::Student(string studentID, string firstName, string lastName, string emailAddress, int age, DegreeProgram degreeProgram, int daysInCourse[])
{
    studentID = studentID;
    firstName = firstName;
    lastName = lastName;
    emailAddress = emailAddress;
    age = age;
    degreeProgram = degreeProgram;
    for (int index = 0; index < daysToCompleteArraySize; index++) {
        daysInCourse[index] = daysInCourse[index];

Comment: please edit the header file into the question, not as a comment

Comment: @pm100 #include "degree.hpp"
#include <string>
#pragma once
using std::string;

class Student {

public:
    const static int daysToCompleteArraySize = 3;

private:
    string studentID;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string emailAddress;
    int age;
    DegreeProgram degreeProgram;
    int daysInCourse[daysToCompleteArraySize];

Comment: @DevlenWatkins Don't post additional information in comments. Instead click [edit] under your question and add the information to it.

Comment: I am new to all of this apologies in advance.

Comment: Your constructor declaration has `std::vector<int> daysInCourse[]` as its last argument but the definition has `int daysInCourse[]`. These are not the same type.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is doesnt match

```
Student::Student(string studentID, string firstName, string lastName, string emailAddress, int age, DegreeProgram degreeProgram, int daysInCourse[])

Student(string studentID, string firstName, string lastName, string emailAddress, int age, DegreeProgram degree, std::vector<int> daysInCourse[]);
```

and that second one is very odd, `std::vector<int> daysInCourse[]`

You probably mean

```
Student::Student(string studentID, string firstName, string lastName, string emailAddress, int age, DegreeProgram degreeProgram, std::vector<int> daysInCourse)


Student(string studentID, string firstName, string lastName, string emailAddress, int age, DegreeProgram degree, std::vector<int> daysInCourse);
```

or even better

```
Student::Student(string studentID, string firstName, string lastName, string emailAddress, int age, DegreeProgram degreeProgram, std::vector<int> &daysInCourse)


Student(string studentID, string firstName, string lastName, string emailAddress, int age, DegreeProgram degree, std::vector<int> &daysInCourse);
```

I suspect somebody told you to use `std::vector` instead of a raw array but you did not complete the edit.